# Importing a Tracked Line Geometry (from LineString) in a CSV into QGIS (3.4)

Tags: qgis-3, csv, linestring, trimble

I'm very new to GIS work and I hope this is the right place to post this. I haven't been able to find/understand an explanation on how to deal with my issue so I hope that I'm not asking an already answered question.

I have a CSV file with a LineString with up to several hundred coordinates from a tracked line collection using a Trimble R1 receiver. An example looks like this:

{"type":"LineString","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:4326"}},"coordinates":[[-121.909104624079,56.0290861839679,474.87293563851],[-121.909151121436,56.0290460319473,473.438320804134].... etc]}

I would like to use this LineString as the geometry for the lines when they're imported into QGIS (3.4), is there a way to do this by converting them into a wkt format or some other way to import this information into a layer that's relatively non-labour intensive (i.e. not separating out each point coordinate into its own column)?

When I add it as a layer using the add delimited text layer and set the geometry as a wkt and select the correct column in the csv none of my lines appear in the layer. It doesn't seem like my LineString format is recognized as a WKT.